# rspec require lib only in one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, require, refile

I'm using refile gem and wanna test the uploader with rspec. Since I'm using refile only for one model in the app I wanna avoid requiring it in rails_helper. If I try to require it as you see below then I will get `require': cannot load such file -- refile/file_double (LoadError)` error. What should I do?

rails_helper.rb

```
require 'devise'
require "pundit/rspec"
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
```

spec/models/company_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'refile/file_double'
```

Comment: May be you need to write `require: "refile/rails"` instead `refile/file_double`?